# Images are missing in HTML Email Flyer

Tags: html, appsflyer

I am trying to create Email Flyer via HTML,  but when I am sending the email, only the text will show not the images of flyer.

Please suggest how we can add local images in flyer so that when email flyer will be sent, it go with images as well.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Please show an example of your code. Without your code we will be guessing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your image have a absolute URL (not relative URL) , like that:

   <img src="http://relaxitblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/javascript-style-guide-Semicolons.jpg">
2. Then, make sure have permission to access this file on server.